# JavaFX Setting an Image to ImageView after selecting it

Tags: java, javafx

I want to select a picture on the HDD with the help of JFileChooser and display it in the GUI. 
 The problem is that I can't set the selected image to the ImageView. I think I'm doing something completely wrong but I also tried various other ways to display it for example with BufferedImage but nothing worked for me. 
 I don't get behind this, please help me.

Controller:

```js
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;


public class WindowController {
 
 @FXML private Button btn_load;
 @FXML private TextField text_path;
 @FXML private ImageView img_frame;
 
 public Main main;
 
 public void setMain(Main main) {
  this.main = main;
 }
 

 @FXML
 public void handle_load() throws MalformedURLException{
  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
  int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  
  if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   text_path.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
   File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
   String localURL = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
   img_frame.setImage(localURL);
  }
 }
}
```

And the fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.WindowController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="img_frame" fitHeight="516.0" fitWidth="627.0" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="114.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="97.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="142.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="142.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="114.0" />
      <HBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="885.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btn_load" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle_load" text="Load Image" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
            <TextField fx:id="text_path" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="0.0" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You need to put an image into the image view not a URL - img_frame.setImage(new Image(localURL));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of adding it to a url, just add

```
img_view.setImage(new Image(url));
```

It will fix your problem